# How to use two helper functions in main script from another script

Tags: python

TypeError: _slow_trap_ramp() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

```
def demag_chip(self):
    coil_probe_constant = float(514.5)
    field_sweep = [50 * i * (-1)**(i + 1) for i in range(20, 0, -1)] #print as list
    for j in field_sweep:
        ramp = self._slow_trap_ramp(j)

def _set_trap_ramp(self):
    set_trap_ramp = InstrumentsClass.KeysightB2962A.set_trap_ramp
    return set_trap_ramp

def _slow_trap_ramp(self):
    slow_trap_ramp = ExperimentsSubClasses.FraunhoferAveraging.slow_trap_ramp
    return slow_trap_ramp
```

Comment: You need to fix the indentation to have a better sense of what's happening so we can help you out more

Comment: How did you import the helper class? It seems you are trying to call the class by the name of the file as opposed to class name.

Comment: Do you know how to **import** objects from other modules? This is what you need to do, import your two functions from `InstrumentClass.py` in `MainTests.py`.

Comment: I had imported everything, and my code has been updated, so it should be more clear now, but still not sure why I am getting this error

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your code extract contains methods of some class, whose full definition is not shown, and you are calling one method from another method (`self._slow_trap_ramp(j)`). When you call a method, Python automatically passes `self` before any other arguments. So you need to change `def _slow_trap_ramp(self)` to `def _slow_trap_ramp(self, j)`.

**Update in response to comment**

To really help, we would need to see more of the class you are writing, and also some info on the other objects you are calling. But I am going to go out on a limb and guess that your code looks something like this:

**InstrumentsClass.py**

```
class KeysightB2962A
    def __init__(self):
        ...
    def set_trap_ramp(self):
        ...
```

**ExperimentsSubClasses.py**

```
class FraunhoferAveraging
    def __init__(self):
        ...
    def slow_trap_ramp(self, j):
        ...
```

**Current version of main.py**

```
import InstrumentsClass, ExperimentsSubClasses
class MyClass
    def __init__(self)
        ...
    def demag_chip(self):
        coil_probe_constant = float(514.5)
        field_sweep = [50 * i * (-1)**(i + 1) for i in range(20, 0, -1)] #print as list
        for j in field_sweep:
            ramp = self._slow_trap_ramp(j)
    def _set_trap_ramp(self):
        set_trap_ramp = InstrumentsClass.KeysightB2962A.set_trap_ramp
        return set_trap_ramp
    def _slow_trap_ramp(self):
        slow_trap_ramp = ExperimentsSubClasses.FraunhoferAveraging.slow_trap_ramp
        return slow_trap_ramp

if __name__ == "__main__":
    my_obj = MyClass()
    my_obj.demag_chip()
```

If this is the case, then these are the main problems:

1. Python passes `self` and `j` to `MyClass._slow_trap_ramp`, but you've only defined it to accept `self` (noted above),
2. you are using class methods from `KeysightB2962A` and `FraunhoferAveraging` directly instead of instantiating the class and using the instance's methods, and
3. you are returning references to the methods instead of calling the methods.

You can fix all of these by changing the code to look like this (see embedded comments):

**New version of main.py**

```
import InstrumentsClass, ExperimentsSubClasses
class MyClass
    def __init__(self)
        # create instances of the relevant classes (note parentheses at end)
        self.keysight = InstrumentsClass.KeysightB2962A()
        self.fraun_averaging = ExperimentsSubClasses.FraunhoferAveraging()
    def demag_chip(self):
        coil_probe_constant = float(514.5)
        field_sweep = [50 * i * (-1)**(i + 1) for i in range(20, 0, -1)] #print as list
        for j in field_sweep:
            ramp = self._slow_trap_ramp(j)
    def _set_trap_ramp(self):
        # call instance method (note parentheses at end)
        return self.keysight.set_trap_ramp()
    def _slow_trap_ramp(self, j): # accept both self and j
        # call instance method (note parentheses at end)
        return self.fraun_averaging.slow_trap_ramp(j)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    my_obj = MyClass()
    my_obj.demag_chip()
```

Comment: One more problem, how do I use the _set_trap_ramp? It's basically an initialization but I can't get it to go?

def demag_chip(self): self._set_trap_ramp field_sweep = [50 * i * (-1)**(i + 1) for i in range(20, 0, -1)] for j in field_sweep: self._slow_trap_ramp(j)

Comment: See edits above. If this doesn't address your question, can you submit a minimal, complete, verifiable example? https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

The error is straightforward.

```
ramp = self._slow_trap_ramp(j)
```

You are calling this method with an argument `j`, but the method doesn't take an argument (other than `self`, which is used to pass the object).

Re-define your method to accept an argument if you want to pass it one:

```
def _slow_trap_ramp(self, j):
```

Comment: One more problem, how do I use the _set_trap_ramp? It's basically an initialization but I can't get it to go?

Comment: def demag_chip(self):
        self._set_trap_ramp
        field_sweep = [50 * i * (-1)**(i + 1) for i in range(20, 0, -1)] 
        for j in field_sweep:
            self._slow_trap_ramp(j)